# Suppose $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $W$. Then $T(0) = 0$. Does that mean $Tv = 0$ implies $v = 0$ or that $0$ is just always mapped to $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does that mean $Tv = 0$ implies $v = 0$ or that $0$ is just always mapped to $0$? I'm thinking the second one since the there could be other values that $T$ maps to $0$.

Comment: Please put the full question in the post. Letters don't start on the outside of the envelope; posts don't start on the title line.

Comment: If $T : V \rightarrow W$ is the zero map with $V \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, then for every $v \neq 0$, one has $T(v)=0$. So  $T(v)=0$ does not imply $v=0$.

Comment: For a linear map $T$, the proposition $Tv=0\implies v=0$ is true if and only if $T$ is one-one (which is not always the case). The second statement is true. A linear map always preserves the additive identity so $T0=0$. Further as you study kernels, isomorphism theorems, these concepts will become more clear & obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, and here's a set of examples to demonstrate.

Let $V = W = \mathbb{R}^2$, and consider the following three linear maps from $V$ to $W$ (I'll leave it to you to prove that they're all linear):

- $T_1(x, y) = (x, y)$ is the identity map
- $T_2(x, y) = (x, 0)$ sends the second component of every vector to zero
- $T_3(x, y) = (0, 0)$ is the zero map

Notice that $T_1(v) = 0 \iff v = 0$, but the same isn't true for the other maps - for $T_2$ any vector of the form $(0, y)$ will get sent to zero, while for $T_3$ *every* vector goes to zero.

If you're studying this in linear algebra right now, then you will probably soon learn about something called the *kernel* of a linear operator, which is the set of vectors that map to zero. So $\ker(T_1) = \{(0, 0)\}$, $\ker(T_2) = \{(0, y) : y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\ker(T_3) = \mathbb{R}^2$. The kernel has a lot of useful properties and applications, which would not be the case if it were always trivial.